# Can I carry my makeup like kajal eyeliner hair serum on my check in bags?

Tags: luggage, india, domestic-travel, prohibited-items

Can I carry my makeup like kajal eyeliner hair serum on my check in bags? Kolkata to Chennai flight

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, it is only in carry-on that that liquids are limited.

And even there in most countries you can take small amounts (up to 100 ml or 3.4 oz each and a one liter/one quart bag to hold the bottles).